Orthogonal hyperbolic coordinates
On the plane, consider an hyperbolic coordinate $\alpha$ given by
$$ \alpha = x^2 - \beta y^2 $$
with $\beta$ a fixed parameter
I want to find a change of coordinates from cartesian coordinates, to another coordinates $(\alpha, \gamma)$ such that they are orthogonal everywhere.
I tried to find what kind of $\gamma$ would satisfy the condition. Such function would have to satisfy
$$ \frac{ \partial_x \gamma }{ \partial_y \gamma } = \frac{ \beta y }{ x } $$
I am a bit stumped here, as after looking at this for a while, I have the suspicion this is not even an exact differential. However it would seem odd that you cannot construct an orthogonal curve to $\alpha$ everywhere.
What would be the correct way to find such orthogonal coordinates?

By calculations, $d\alpha=2(xdx-\beta ydy)$. For any $\alpha_0\in\mathbb{R}$, we know $d\alpha=0$ in the axis $\alpha=\alpha_0$. Then the $\underline{perpendicular}$ axis $\gamma=\gamma(x,y)=\gamma_0$ satisfies $d\gamma=\beta ydx + xdy=0$ at $\{\gamma=\gamma_0\}\cap \{\alpha=\alpha_0\}$. Hence, $\gamma=\gamma(x,y)=x^{\beta}y$.
